# How to fix multiple dropdown with comma separated ids?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, drop-down-menu

I have two dropdown one is user list and another is selected userlist.i want to list only non selected users to list
my arrays

```
$this->getusers=
 [1] => Array
        (
            [adminID] => 28
            [UserName] => a
            [Password] => 345bcc5369bb7408dcfce4a1a97a936cc961499ec696c5161d3d3ffb99e2f179
            [salt] => a147b357bd7f351644e784506d87f110
            [email] => ar@mjsofttech.com
            [profile_id] => 2
            [E_id] => 11
            [R_head] => 27
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [adminID] => 27
            [UserName] => d
            [Password] => d2111a96534b5ac543234ebcd759a2691535ecc43be575aadff463cc4dfbc0cd
            [salt] => e9eef7d916e6c9ad5ea64790b8f93a35
            [email] => d@mjsofttech.com
            [profile_id] => 1
            [E_id] => 13
            [R_head] => 26
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [adminID] => 34
            [UserName] => f
            [Password] => 955cd016646459cb38bd5ba3454724d529a568f2ce0090a3afbc9d50369ddb65
            [salt] => 0a6989ec15b6454a24722e8832cd0cd9
            [email] => f@mjsofttech.com
            [profile_id] => 2
            [E_id] => 123
            [R_head] => 27
        )

[4] => Array
    (
        [adminID] => 33
        [UserName] => j
        [Password] => f2852fb272e1ff58c0562096e94d3d1d9b72c6ed7c0c90e67787179918e58153
        [salt] => 9a547a397db3f342519c21fb934aeb87
        [email] => j@mjsofttech.com
        [profile_id] => 3
        [E_id] => 12
        [R_head] => 29
    )
```

i tried multi select with in_array function

```
$this->editproject=
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Project_name] => test
            [p_id] => 1
            [gid] => 28,33
        )
```

here gid is comma separated ,
Here `28,33` are selected users so i dont want to list 28 and 33 in users list

```
<?php foreach ($this->getusers as $users): ?>
    <select name="" id="lstview" class="form-control" size="8" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="<?php echo $users['adminID'] ?>"<?php if(!in_array(  $this->editproject[0]['gid'],$users['adminID'])){ ?>selected="selected"<?php } ?>><?php echo $users['UserName'] ?></option>
    </select>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

bad luck i didnt get any output.any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Your select shouldn't be in foreach, just the options should. Your select has an empty name attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is you took complete select element inside foreach, you should take select tag outside of foreach

```
<select name="" id="lstview" class="form-control" size="8" multiple="multiple">
<?php
foreach ($this->getusers as $users) {
    $selected = array_column($this->editproject, 'gid');
    if (!in_array($users['adminID'], $selected)) {
        echo "<option value='" . $users['adminID'] . "' selected>" . $users['UserName'] . "</option>";
    }
}
?>
</select>
```

You had the wrong syntax of `in_array`.
I think you may need [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to fetch all `gid`s and check in_aray

[in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) — Checks if a value exists in an array

**Syntax:**

```
in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = FALSE ] ) : bool
```

Comment: Thing is he don't want to list them, your code will still list them but just not keep them "selected".

Comment: @rahul meshram thanks for your reply..but code gets error

Comment: @RahulMeshram list all...i dont want to list them :-(

Comment: @traker `!in_array($users['adminID'], $selected` you means whichever adminIds satisfy this condition only should come and will be selected is it?

Comment: @RahulMeshram $selected ids don't want to list..eg 28,33 sleeted so i don't want  this ids in list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191726/discussion-between-traker-and-rahul-meshram).

Answer (score 0):

If you want skip the selected ids not to appear in the drop down, you can just put a condition to continue the loop and fetch the next value.

```
$selected = $this->editproject[0]['gid'];
foreach ($this->getusers as $users):
if(in_array($users['adminID'], $selected){ continue; }
/** rest of the logic **/
endforeach;
```

Comment: Why should OP try this? A little explanation would be nice